# Loading data in jQuery modal by passing Id

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using this jquery modal library https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal and wanted to pair it with my datatables.

I want to click on a link in my datatables and pass that Id to the jquery modal which will then load the data from the server based on the Id and then open to display it.

So far this is what I have.

View:

```
@model Data.ViewModels.ApplicationRolesDetailsViewModel
@Html.Partial("Modal/RoleDetails",Model)
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>@Model.ApplicationDetails.Name</h2>
    <hr />
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.Id)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.Name, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12", @readonly = "true" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.Description)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.Description, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.Id)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.Id, new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.SecretKey)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.SecretKey, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12", @readonly = "true" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.SecretKey)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.CreatedOn)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.CreatedOn, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12", @readonly = "true" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.UpdatedOn)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDetails.UpdatedOn, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12", @readonly = "true" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <a href="#roleDetails" class="btn btn-default pull-right" rel="modal:open" id="add">Add</a>
            <table id="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Roles</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-default pull-right" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Datatables script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $("#table").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("GetApplicationRoles", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": form_data,
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "filter":false,
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "searchPlaceholder": " Search"
            },
            "ordering": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        var url = "#roleDetails";
                        return "<a href='" + url + "'>" + data.RoleId+ "</i></a>"
                    }, "name": "RoleId"
                }
            ],
            "responsive": true,
            "processing":true,
            "serverSide": true,
        }).columns.adjust()
        .responsive.recalc();
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
    });
```

This will generate a table that looks like this:

[image]

May I know how should I edit the url variable in my datatables to pass an Id to the modal? Also, how do I take that Id in my modal and load the appropriate variables?

This is the code of the modal partial view

```
@model Data.ViewModels.ApplicationRolesDetailsViewModel
<div id="roleDetails" class="modal"><div class="col-sm-12">
    @if (Model.Roles.Id == null)
    {
        <h2>Add Role</h2>
    }
    else
    {
        <h2>Edit Role</h2>
    }
    <hr />
</div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRole", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
    {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Roles.ApplicationId)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Roles.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Roles.Name, new { @class = "form-control col-sm-12" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: so are you successfully getting `data.RoleName` in datatable? and `"name": "RoleName"` is your datatable column name?

Comment: Yes I am. RoleName is the column of my datatable. I want to know how to pass it to the modal

Comment: so you want to pass `RoleName` to modal popup or `Id`? If `Id` then please explain which `Id` in this case?

Comment: Oh I just realized it. So sorry for the confusion. My data.RoleName has a data.RoleId that is the one that should be passed to the modal popup. I'll edit the question so its clearer. Thank you.

Comment: I changed it to data.RoleId to be passed.